# Calling python function in html page

Tags: python, flask

Ive made  a flask script which runs fine however im trying to display some values in a table on another html page which for some reason is not happening.

i've already tried going through jinja2 documentation and a few other answers but it didn't help much.

the flask file.py

```
    from flask import Flask,render_template,request
    app = Flask(__name__)
    from webscraper import keeda,display_tbl

    @app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def scraper():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            url = request.form['url']
            df=keeda(url)
            return render_template(('completed.html',display_tbl(df)))
        else:
            return render_template('index.html')
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()

the completed.html file
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Summary of Scraped Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is what you got! </h1>
<div>
    {{ display_tbl(df) }}
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

```
here's the error: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'display_tbl' is undefined

i wanted to display a table with values on this page.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting more than what jinja2 can do for you. Please understand jinja2 is just a way to render templates which are eventually html and javascript, nothing fancy. So, in your case you cannot pass a Python function to your jinja2 template and expect that to run fine. What you can do here is to pass the data returned by `display_tbl` while rendering template like this:

```
def scraper():
    ...
    return render_template(('completed.html', data=display_tbl(df)))  # data= is important because this is how you are going to access your data in the template

…

def display_tbl(df):
    …  # Here you should be returning the data you want to display - a list or dict
```

In the template

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Summary of Scraped Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is what you got! </h1>
<div>
    {{ render_data() }}
</div>

<script>
    var d = data | tojson
    function render_data() {
        // implement the logic to handle how your data should be rendered
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is just a rough idea but as you can see you need to change the way you are perceiving jinja2 templates and their interaction with Python or Flask backend.

Comment: I understood,I have solved it the other way round. Thanks!!